# How to create a non interruptive bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a small modal that appears at the top of the screen periodically. When it appears it blocks typing in inputs and scrolling until it goes away. Is there a way to make the modal non-interruptive so that when it appears it doesn't cause focus change or anything else. I want it to be minimally invasive.

Below is my modal:

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin-top:10px;" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a non-interruptive modal, why not use an alert? 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts

A modal interrupts the user by definition.

Comment: Two reasons, 1) My view is long and scrollable and I need something that will be visible regardless of where you are on the page, and 2) I don't want to cause any breaks in the dom by inserting and then hiding an alert.

Comment: You can use a static header area with an alert to achieve what you want. A modal is just not the way to go here.